# Cant connect to school Wi-Fi from Linux

Tags: networking

I recently changes to a new school that actually cares a lot about internet security and they pay their it department an absolute fortune, and i cannot connect to their Wi-Fi from my laptop i bought 6 months prior. They use cyberhound internet security, the students have a separate network from the teachers, then they have a network for all of the other random devices, as well as a spare "Guest" network. I am trying to use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as i used that on my old laptop and for the first 6 months before my new school on my main laptop. I ended up just installing windows for the time being while i figure out why it isn't working. on windows it just comes up with username and password, then, once you are connected, you type setup/ in a web browser and it downloads a .exe file which installs the certificate and all of the printers. Similar on mac except for the certificate and printers part. On Linux however, when you try to connect in the first place, it comes up with the WPA2 Enterprise network screen and if i just enter my username and password and press connect, it tries to connect but fails and you can't even connect in the first place. I managed to extract the certificate to a .cer file which i could install and i even tried using the certificate to connect in the WPA2 Enterprise screen (along with my username and password), but it still does the same thing. I tried talking to my schools IT Department but they said they knew nothing about it (i kinda hoped they could show me to someone who did know), and i have tried searching through different community forums on similar topics, but they mostly just said to connect with the certificate. I would really like to go back to using Ubuntu instead of windows, but i cannot find how. Plz help

Comment: Only the school IT people can help with this. Do they allow Ubuntu 22.04 to access the network? Sounds like they do not want to.

Comment: @David The IT People said that they haven't specifically not allowed linux, they just said they don't know why i am having this problem.

Comment: i think you need set EAP authentification via [WPA_Supplicant](https://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/).

Comment: @Sad3ng i will try connecting in a vm with this on monday, as it is currently the weekend for me.